# xhr.setrequestheader in all ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest

My site has some pages using jquery and some dojo (we are moving to jquery actually). I need to set a common custom header on all ajax requests irrespective of whether it uses jquery or dojo.  Can I do it some thing like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-app':'ios'
    }
});
dojo._xhr_orig = dojo.xhr;
    dojo.xhr = function(/*String*/ method, /*dojo.__XhrArgs*/ args, /*Boolean?*/ hasBody){
        args = args || {};
        args.headers = args.headers || {};

        args.headers['X-app'] = 'ios';

        return dojo._xhr_orig.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

But I need to do this across the site. Is there something where I can change something on XMLHTTPrequest prototype to do this?

Comment: I'd think it'd be easier to just write a custom xhr/request function instead of tinkering with XMLHttpRequest. Then you can use any JS framework to actually construct the request with special headers or other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
          if (s.type == "POST") {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('X-app', 'ios');
          }
});
```

By the way be carefull using upper-case for setting request header, I had some problem with IE6, IE7 and IE8 not setting it properly.

Edited:

This is even better (an not having to worry about case-insensitive):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
          beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-app', 'ios');
          }
});
```

Hope this help you.
Regards.